# Disabling resizing of NSView

Tags: nsview

I am showing a view as sheet using `presentViewControllerAsSheet` API of NSViewController. Is there a way to disable resizing of the view that is presented?

I looked online and there are ways to disable resizing of window but not NSView.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I was able to achieve this by setting preferredContentSize on the view controller in viewDidLoad()

```
[self setPreferredContentSize:self.view.frame.size];
```

Answer (score 1):

@dev answer works for me in Swift 4 (Xcode 9.3)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    preferredContentSize = view.frame.size
}
```

If using storyboard, make sure the class is assigned into the NSViewController.

Comment: it is shocking how long it took me to find this....thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

In Objective-C and macOS 12.3.1 I experience beachballs when using the methods described here earlier. Simply use fixed size constraints to prevent the NSView from resizing.

1. First set the view layout options in IB to 'Inferred (Constraints)'

[image]

2. Set the fixed width/height constraints in IB

[image]

Comment: perfect! after doing this way, I updated "Editor > Update Constraint Constants" and worked

Answer (score 0):

Setting preferredContentSize didn't work for me using Swift 4.0 and XCode 9.2, e.g.:
`self.preferredContentSize = NSSize(width: 448, height: 250)`

However, I can set parameters like minimum size like this in `viewDidAppear()`:
`self.view.window?.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: 448, height: 250)`

I imagine you can disable resize by also setting maximum size and `showsResizeIndicator`. Note that setting these parameters in `viewDidLoad()` did not work.

Answer (score 0):

my two cents for swift / OSX / catalina

Suppose You want a list to be allowed to shrink only vertically (fixed width)

```
override func viewDidAppear() {
    self.setFixedWidth()

}

final private func setFixedWidth(){
    self.view.window?.contentMinSize = NSSize(width: 300, height: 250)
    self.view.window?.contentMaxSize = NSSize(width: 300, height: 1250)
}
```

When dragging you can only expand vertically (not enlarge it).